# How to run schema scripts after running couchbase via docker compose?

Tags: docker-compose, couchbase

I have a schema script `/data/cb-create.sh` that I have made available on a container volume. When I run `docker-compose up`, my server is not initialized at the time `command` is executed. So those commands fail because the server isn't launched just yet. I do not see a `Starting Couchbase Server -- Web UI available at http://<ip>:8091` log line when the .sh script is running to initialize the schema. This is my docker compose file. How can I sequence it properly?

```
version: '3'

services:
 couchbase:
    image: couchbase:community-6.0.0
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
      - 8092:8092
      - 8093:8093
      - 8094:8094
      - 11210:11210
    volumes:
      - ./:/data

    command: /bin/bash -c "/data/cb-create.sh"
    container_name: couchbase
 

volumes:
 kafka-data:
```

Answer (score 1):

First: You should choose either an entrypoint or a command statement.
I guess an option is to write a small bash script where you put these commands in order.
Then in the command you specify running that bash script.

Comment: I already have `command` section in my docker-compose file in which I am invoking that cb-create.sh bash script.

Comment: You can not have a entrypoint and a command. So whatever is in the entrypoint should be in that bash script too.